# Google maps ios: Mapview Route vertical polyline always points to north or top of location arrow

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have implemented the basic functioning of Google Maps IOS in my app.

I have to set bearing of mapview always points to Top OR North.

I need if I click on navigate button the mapview should animate to Top of location arrow same as google maps ios app does.

The arrow should always fix and points to north, Only mapview will animate or change bearing as per turn or location.

THIS IS WE SAID RIGHT[image] 
[image]
THIS IS WRONG>

Comment: What do you expect to see in the second picture?

Comment: the second picture is the issue. The route should be on Top of Arrow point and always face to North. As shown in first picture.

Comment: So it sounds like you want the arrow in the second picture to be pointing to the east so that the route goes through the top of the arrow. Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: @not_a_bot u got any solution?

Comment: @anshul-systematix i am facing same problem with apple map, how we can solve can you please guide us

Answer (score 0):

I was calling direction API for route showing and calculating. And in response they provide html_instructions for route steps. the first index of steps response always return a head with respect to North direction.And we can set bearing according to head we got from instructions.

```
if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"east"]) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:90];
            locationMarker_.rotation=90;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"eastsouth"] || [HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"southeast"] ) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:135];
            locationMarker_.rotation=135;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"north"]) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:0];
            locationMarker_.rotation=0;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"northeast"] ||[HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"eastnorth"] ) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:45];
            locationMarker_.rotation=45;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"south"]) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:180];
            locationMarker_.rotation=180;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"southwest"] || [HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"westsouth"]) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:-135];
            locationMarker_.rotation=-135;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"west"]) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:-90];
            locationMarker_.rotation=-90;
        }
        else if ([HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"westnorth"] || [HeadTo_Str isEqualToString:@"northwest"]) {
            [mapView animateToBearing:-45];
            locationMarker_.rotation=-45;
        }
```

Comment: i have eject requirement can u help me