# map points always to the north?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, mobile

I want to implement solution with javascripte that draw itinerary but the map always points to the north. 
I want to do this but usinggoogle maps and  javascript and i want to point it to my next direction
. Any one have idea how can I do this Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it always points to the north?

Comment: I do mean  I want to rotate my map in order to show the next destionation. The same context as in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141815/google-maps-ios-mapview-route-vertical-polyline-always-points-to-north-or-top-o

Comment: You should add at least a piece of code, I have no idea how to help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Maps Javascript API support map rotation, but you can apply  a 2D rotation, which angle is specified in the parameter, to the outer div of the Google Maps. For example `transform: rotate(45deg);`

Look at [this JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xns2h61m/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference and here you will finde a function called setHeading that give you the possibility to sets the compass heading for aerial imagery measured in degrees from cardinal direction North.

```
setHeading(0);
```

should point to north. Is this your problem?